# Cloud data Security in Network

Tags: cloud, ip-restrictions, spring-cloud-security

How Can uses be restricted on the basis on IP address in the network on cloud platform? If I have assigned specific IP Address to my employees and they move to other IP they should not access my network. What solution will help in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Packet Filter` at the edge of your entry point. Lets say in a cloud environment you use a Jumpbox to get into the environment. You can implement a Packet filter or ACL.

On the other hand if you have a web server, you can define rules in `.htaccess` for Apache stuff.

Comment: your answer was quite valuable but my query was that if some of my employees moves out of the office and working remotely and wants to access the network in that situation that might not work, I guess.

Comment: there are 2 ways to do it , 
1. Use a Jumbox and allow your employees to access that machine from their homes etc. this way you will have ONE entry point to monitor , plus you can use some utility like 'fail2ban' etc to ban someone trying to access . {This is the preferred way}

2. if your servers are exposed to public , and u want to restrict their access from outside, then u can do this on the instance's sec group.